# Issue with While loop going through record set from query

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2, ms-access-2013

I have an issue with my iteration through the data returned by a query. I am using Delphi XE2 and MS Access as the DBMS.

I have the issue in every play I try to iterate through the record set, it will only process the first record and then skip the rest, the query is correct because I use a RecCount function and it returns the correct amount of records but the While loop does not go through the records, it iterates once and proceeds on.

Below is parts of the coding:

```
DB : TADOQuery; //Where DB is this

//Only retrieves the OrderIDs belonging to that username as the Object searchs for its own information using the orderID
DB.Close;
DB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT OrderID FROM tblOrders WHERE Username = ' + '''' + pUsername + '''';
DB.ExecSQL;
DB.Open;

ShowMessage(IntToStr(DB.RecordCount));
fCount := 0;
while NOT(db.Eof) AND (fCount < 10) do
Begin
  Inc(fCount);

fArr[fCount] := TOrder.Create(DB.FieldByName('OrderID').AsInteger); //Creating of the object

DB.Next;
end;

DB.Close;
```

So that is the code, as you can see the ShowMessage returns the record count and it returns 3( The correct amount of records for that username) . But the loop only iterates once and I do not understand why.

Thanks
Ben

**EDIT**

It seems that this segment of the code prevents the loop from iterating for some reason, without it the loop iterates through and returns all the correct values. With help from @Alexandre

```
fArr[fCount] := TOrder.Create(DB.FieldByName('OrderID').AsInteger); <-- Error
```

To Fix the issue this is how my code now finally looks, it works correctly.

```
var
OrderArr : ARRAY[1..10] of Integer;
k, iIndex : Integer;
begin
opendb('DB.mdb');

//Only retrieves the OrderIDs belonging to that username as the Object searchs for its own information using the orderID
  DB.Close;
  DB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT OrderID FROM tblOrders WHERE Username = ' + '''' + pUsername + '''';
  DB.Open;
  DB.DisableControls;

  fCount := 0;
  try
   DB.First;
   while not DB.EOF do
   begin
    // do something here with each record
    Inc(fCount);

    OrderArr[fCount] := DB.FieldByName('OrderID').AsInteger;
    DB.Next;
   end;
  finally
    DB.EnableControls;
   end;

  for k := 1 to fCount do
  Begin

  fArr[k] := TOrder.Create(OrderArr[k]);

  End;
```

That seems to work, I have no idea why it doesn't work with the create in the first loop. Hopefully someone can help still

Thanks
Ben

Comment: What is the reason for `DB.ExecSQL` and `DB.Open`? You also should use parameters

Comment: And please show more code: **Where** is `fCount` declared? **Where** is `DB` declared? What is happening on `TOrder.Create()`? Did you load the order inside this constructor and reusing `DB` or `fCount` for that? Looks like a sideeffect to me

Comment: A simple test will show you: Uncomment the line with `TOrder.Create()` and watch the loop with the debugger

Comment: Try navigating to the first record before the loop: DB.First; while ...

Comment: @SirRufo For Some reason it was the TOrder.Create(). I put it in a separate loop and now it works. Look at the edit. Thanks

Comment: You should take care of that reason. I guess that you are reusing the query `DB` or the variable `fCount`

Comment: @SirRufo Both are used for the first time in that Create(). I am not reusing either of them. Is there maybe a way to clear the query DB or something

Comment: You did not show us all of the related code. So we do not know, if `DB` or `fCount` are local, global or field variables. So we can only guess. To stop any sideeffects use only local variables and create a query instance for this method. Now even recurse calls will not break your method

Comment: If you remove the 'DB.First' from your working version, and call `ExecSQL` before openning, does it still work?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I owe you a beer if the `TOrder.Create()` **does not call** implicit something like `DB.Close; DB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderID =' + ...`. You see the side effect? ;o) - This is just a guess, but my crystal ball is very clear today - if not, you got a beer for free :o) So we are still waiting for the OP to show the relevant code

Comment: @Sir - That's quite possible. My thinking was the 'execsql' to return the record count, scrolls to the end. And then 'open' does nothing. I may of course be wrong.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The second - now working code - has no `DB.ExecSQL;`, so this cannot be the problem. `ExecSQL` will execute the select and `Open` will execute the select again and returns the dataset

Comment: @Sir - 1 - That was my point, the working code has no 'execsql', 'execsql' is part of the problem. 2 - You may be right, if execsql does not leave the dataset in active state. However it still needs to be tested.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Tested - does nothing, only wasting energy

Comment: Both are global variables, called at the top of the class under private. @SirRufo

Comment: Please add your working solution as an answer rather than editing your question

Comment: @Ben Again, please add **all** relevant code to your question. This **includes** the code inside `TOrder.Create`. We cannot answer to this question, because we do not know what happens inside the constructor and it is not possible to read from your screen, disc or mind ...

Answer (score 2):

Please try this pattern. It must work as expected otherwise there is something really wrong in your code. Note that DB.ExecSQL makes no sense here, once you are going to open a query, not execute some other statement like INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE.
Also, if your DataSet (DB) is not attached to a visual control, consider enclosing the loop in DisableControls and EnableControls calls. This has a huge impact on speed of the loop when you have many records in an ADO DataSet.

```
DB: TADOQuery;

DB.Close;
DB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT OrderID FROM tblOrders WHERE Username = ' + '''' + pUsername + '''';
DB.Open;
DB.DisableControls;
try
  DB.First;
  while not DB.EOF do
  begin
    // do something here with each record
    DB.Next;
  end;
finally
  DB.EnableControls;
end;
```

Comment: I used your pattern, I figured out a way to get around the issue. It seems that the `code` fArr[fCount] := TOrder.Create(DB.FieldByName('OrderID').AsInteger); `code` stops the loop from iterating for some reason. I Simply loaded the orderIDs into a temporary array and then have another For loop to go through those values and create them in the OrderArr array. I will put it as a edit for my OP. @Alexandre